# How H.C.F. is helping to solve this question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question :

The largest number that divides $17, 23, 35, 59$ to leave the same remainder in each case.

The Answer suggests that the required number is : $HCF (23-17, 35-23, 59-35, 59-17)$

I am asking for the clear explanation of how this approach is helping to solve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(*)$ Let $x\lt y \lt z \lt w$ be positive integers and $r \in \mathbb N$ be such that when the integers $x,y,z,w$ are divided by $r$, have same remainder.

Now using division algorithm, we have
$$x=x_1 r + b$$
$$y=y_1 r + b$$
$$z=z_1 r + b$$
$$w=w_1 r + b$$
for some $x_1,y_1,z_1,w_1,b\in \mathbb Z.$ From this we see that $$r|(y-x), r|(z-y), r|(w-z), r|(w-x).$$

This last condition is satisfied by any $r\in \mathbb N$ satisfying $(*)$. So the largest such $r$ is...